# How to match fields in cakephp that are not present in database

Tags: cakephp, controllers

How to match new_password and confirm_password fields when they are not in database?

Hi... I would like to know how I would be able to match my fields "new_password" and "confirm_password", they are not stored in database they are just used for matching purpose in Change Password module.

I tried this but it didn't worked:

```
if($this->data['User']['new_password'] != $this->data['User']['confirm_password'] ) {
  $this->Session->setFlash("New password and Confirm password field do not match");
} else {
  $this->data['User']['password'] = $this->data['User']['new_password'];
  $this->data['User']['id'] = $this->User->id;

  if($this->User->save($this->data)) {
    $this->Session->setFlash("Password updated");
    $this->redirect('/users/login');
  }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean with "didn't work"? Do you get any errors?

Comment: Its Working fine but new_password and confirm_password matching is not taking place.... no matter if the fields are filled with the same data or not it updates the password in the backend.

Comment: Did you check with `debug` the content of `$this->data`?

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
// check for empty value

if( !empty( $this->data['User']['new_password'] ) && !empty( $this->data['User']['confirm_password'] ) ) {

   if( $this->data['User']['new_password'] != $this->data['User']['confirm_password']) {

       $this->Session->setFlash("New password and Confirm password field do not match");

   } else {

       $this->data['User']['password'] = $this->data['User']['new_password'];
       $this->data['User']['id'] = $this->User->id;

       if( $this->User->save($this->data) ) {

          $this->Session->setFlash("Password updated");
          $this->redirect('/users/login');

       } else {

          $this->Session->setFlash('Password update fail');

       }
   }

} else {

   $this->Session->setFlash('Enter New password and Confirm password');

}
```